# RxTest is still using libswiftXCTest.dylib

Tags: ios, rx-swift, rxtest

I'm facing an issue of "`Disallowed framework`" when submitting to App Store. The issue is as follows

"`ITMS-90726: Disallowed frameworks - Your app submission contains usages of the restricted framework libswiftXCTest.dylib. Remove these, rebuild and resubmit.`"

Upon my research, I found that RxTest framework is still using restricted framework `libswiftXCTest.dylib`

**Xcode Version** : 11.6

**RxSwift Version** : 5.1.1

1. How do I solve this issue ?
2. Has RxTest resolved this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't import RxTest into your application. It should only be imported into the test target, not the application target.

Answer (score 4):

We had the same issue on our project. We used `Carthage` and in the `copy-frameworks` build phase we had also included the `RxTest` framework.
Removing it from the build phase should solve the issue.